# Open recent project in new window stay behind

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

Since the last version of PhpStorm (2017.1) when we opening recent project or directory in new window, the new window stay behind the current one.

Is there any way to avoid this ?

I went into the settings `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings`, I found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid this ?

Unfortunately not (I'm having the same here on Windows 10) -- it's a bug (regression).

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167068
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157113

Watch those tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.